# MySQL query did not execute--returning that "colume1=MAX(colume1)" incorrect

Tags: mysql, database

I ran the below MySQL query through PHP, but it did not execute--returning that  `colume1=MAX(colume1)` incorrect

What is wrong in the below query

```
select colume from table_name where colume1=MAX(colume1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT colume
    FROM table_name
    WHERE colume1 = (SELECT MAX(colume1) FROM table_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `colume`, MAX(column1) as column1 FROM table_name
```